# Why is the largest invariant factor of $A-xI$ the minimal polynomial of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

From what I see the definition of minimal polynomial is the polynomial of smallest degree that $A$ is a root of.
Invariant factors are the diagonal entries of the Smith Normal Form of a matrix.

I understand that since determinant is unchanged by row and column operations, $\det(A-xI)=\det(SNF(A-xI))$, hence the characteristic polynomial is the product of the diagonal entries of $\det(SNF(A-xI))$. 
But how can I show that the minimal polynomial as defined above, is the largest invariant factor (which I know is a common multiple of all the other invariant factors).

Any comment or hint is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

minimal polynomial of a quasi-diagonal matrix is the least common multiple of minimal polynomial of diagonal terms.
**Proof:**

[image]

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack.